# Functional calls get blocked in Angular2 (they are sanitized)

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-forms

Hi i have an  footer **div** in that i'm appending **innerHtml** from typescript file

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="footerbar" [innerHTML]="printProgressfooterHtmlContent"></div>
```

**TypeScriptCode:**`

```
this.printProgressfooterHtmlContent = '<ul class="nav navbar-nav footerNavBarLeft"><li class="backButtonLi"><a href="#/about"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i><h4 class="footerDone">BACK</h4></a></li></ul><ul  class="nav navbar-nav footerNavBarRight"><li class="backButtonLi LiSeperator"><a class="footerProgressLeftAtag"><h4 class="footerDone">|</h4></a></li><li><a ><h4 class="footerDone" (click)="myFunc()">GROUPS</h4></a></li></ul>';
```

In here i'm calling a function **myFunc()** but when the compiler gets loaded i get an warning as **WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content** in console.

Please provide a proper solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Angular is just sanitizing the content to avoid injections. You're good, there's nothing else to do (if I remember, in Angular 2, you had to sanitize it yourself, now it's done automatically and it warns you when you're not in prod mode).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the DOMSanitizer:

```
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser'
```

...

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer)
```

...

```
this.printProgressfooterHtmlContent = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<ul class="nav navbar-nav foo...');
```

Comment: nope its not working. Now there is no warning in the console but couldn't call the function